# Limitation of memory usage in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, memorycache

I use `IMemoryCache` in my project. I wonder what will happen if my app pushes many long-living objects in the cache. Can it occupy all the available memory? Could I globally define the maximum memory for the app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was written a year ago so I'm going to assume you're using `v1.x.x` of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` package.

Since there isn't a `SizeLimit` property in the `MemoryCacheOptions` like `v2.x.x`, after digging around into the code for a while I found the following line of documentation.

https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs#L329

```
/// This is called after a Gen2 garbage collection. We assume this means there was memory pressure.
/// Remove at least 10% of the total entries (or estimated memory?).
```

Thus the package will eat up as much memory as the OS will allow your code to have. When it reaches that limit it will start compacting (evicting) cache entries.

With `v2.x.x` you can set the limit manually using `SizeLimit` property and you can even set the amount of compaction when the limit is hit `CompactionPercentage`.

Comment: Does SizeLimit means size in bytes?

Comment: In addition, SizeLimit doesn't have a unit. You need to set size when you set cache entry.